# The four fundamental subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $b$ is in column space $A$, this implies that $Ax=b$.

Given $y$ is in the left nullspace of $A$, this implies that $y^{T}A=0$

Given that $d$ is in the row space of $A$, this implies that $Ax=d^{T}$? Is this correct?

Given that $z$ is in the nullspace of $A$, this implies that $Az=0$

Also, is $A^{T}y$ = $y^{T}A$?

Are all of the above statements correct?

Comment: The second and forth are correct. But the first and third don't make sense since you haven't stated what $x$ and $z$ are.

Comment: Given that $d$ is in the row space of $A$, this implies that $A^{T}x=d$

Comment: The last one is almost true. Consider $(A^T y)^T$. It equals $y^T (A^T)^T = y^T A$. So they aren't equal, but they are transposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is an $(m x n)$ matrix with real entries, then...

I think you're on the right track in the first statement. More precisely, $b \in col(A)$ implies that Ax = b has a solution. There is some vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that Ax = b. The column space of A tells us what b vectors are possible.

Your second statement is correct.

The third statement is incorrect. If $ d \in row(A)$ then $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be expressed as some linear combination of the rows of A. We can think of multiplication on the left as forming a linear combination of the rows. So, $d \in row(A)$ implies there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}^m $ with $y^TA = d^T$

Fourth statement has the same minor problem that the first has but, I think your thinking is correct, it just lacks precision.

In the last statement, I think what you're getting at is the two ways of thinking about vectors in the left null space of A. If a vector $y$ is in the left null space of A then both $y^TA =0$ and $A^Ty =0$. So, in this specific case, when y is in the null space of A, then yes, $y^TA = 0 = A^Ty$.